# Exchange Message Tracking only showing messages internal messages

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003

We are in a migration phase from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010, so we still have all external email arriving in to our 2003 server, `OLDEXCHANGE`. All mailboxes are now on the new server, `EXCHANGE2010`, so messages are routed to that mailbox server accordingly.

I have a case of emails going missing, but I can see from our external anti-spam service (Symantec) that is is being delivered to `OLDEXCHANGE` okay.

---

If I run a search in the Exchange 2003 "Message Tracking Centre" for the message, I find it and the log tree looks something like this:

```
+ oldexchange.mydomain.com
    exchange2010.mydomain.com
```

The log entries for the root node look like this:

```
5/22/2013 9:23 AM  SMTP: Message Submitted to Advanced Queuing
5/22/2013 9:23 AM  SMTP: Started Message Submission to Advanced Queue
5/22/2013 9:23 AM  SMTP: Message Submitted to Categorizer
5/22/2013 9:23 AM  SMTP: Message Categorized and Queued for Routing
5/22/2013 9:23 AM  SMTP: Started Outbound Transfer of Message
5/22/2013 9:23 AM  SMTP: Message Routed and Queued for Remote Delivery
5/22/2013 9:23 AM  SMTP: Message transferred to exchange2010.mydomain.com through SMTP
```

And for the subnode like this:

```
The tracking database on exchange2010.mydomain.com is not available or the message has left the Exchange organization.  Facility: Microsoft Exchange Management ID no: c1032751  Microsoft Exchange Management
```

---

When I look on the new server and run the "Tracking Log Explorer", I don't get any results for RECEIVE messages, only messages from STOREDRIV that seem to be local messages between users.

[image]

---

How do I find this message? It's not appearing in the user's mailbox, but I can see it leaving the old server.

Comment: Is there a reason you were not having the 2010 CAS/HT handle all your mail as it should be doing in a 2003/2010 coexistence model?

Comment: Mostly because we're still transitioning. Eventually we'll ditch the 2003 server entirely. As far as we can tell, mail is being delivered okay, it's just messages from a particular address that seem to be going astray, and I can't see from any logging where it's getting lost after leaving the old 2003 server.